# Run a command in all sub-folders in a batch file

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have a batchfile that looks like this:

```
IF EXIST icon.ico (
    attrib -S -H -R desktop.ini
    echo f | xcopy /H /Y "%~dp0desktop.ini.txt" desktop.ini
    attrib +S +H +A desktop.ini
)
```

This works perfectly for my needs.
My question is how do I make this run in all sub-folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I a run command in all subdirectories in a batch file?

You can use `for /r` for this.

Use following batch file:

```
for /r "starting_directory" %%a in (.) do (
  pushd %%a
  if exist icon.ico (
    attrib -s -h -r desktop.ini
    echo f | xcopy /h /y "%~dp0desktop.ini.txt" desktop.ini
    attrib +s +h +a desktop.ini
    ) 
  popd 
  )
```

---

#### for /r - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders)

> Syntax
>
> `FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command`
>
> Key
>
> `drive:path`  : The folder tree where the files are located.
>
> `set`         : A set of one or more files. Wildcards must be used.
>                    If (set) is a period character (.) then FOR will
>                    loop through every folder.
>
> `command`     : The command(s) to carry out, including any
>                    command-line parameters.
>
> %%parameter` : A replaceable parameter:
>                    in a batch file use %%G (on the command line %G)

Source [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).

Comment: I already figured this out before seeing your answer. Your solution is identical to mine, thanks!